# How to set iptables to access MySQL?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, iptables

I need to access mysql from another server using a custom port and restrict access to this other servers IP. How do I get this done?

If I understand correctly I should forward the traffic that comes to lets say port 33306 to 127.0.0.1:3306 by something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 33306 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3306
```

This is not working and I don't get why.

My iptables look like this:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 149 packets, 8788 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            tcp dpt:33306 redir ports 3306

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    22271   10M ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:443 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2     8494 7799K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    10012 1177K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4        7   352 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
5        3   117 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
6        5   772 ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
7        2   140 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1194
8        1    40 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3338 packets, 1926K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

mysql is listening:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1028/mysqld
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most immediate problem is that your NAT rule applies only to traffic destined for `127.0.0.1` but **not** coming in the loopback interface.  Pretty much by definition, there won't **be** any such traffic.  Remove the `-d 127.0.0.1` from your `PREROUTING` rule.

Your second problem is that `mysqld` is only listening on the loopback interface.  You'll need to get it to listen on the external NIC as well, if you want to talk to an external system.  I don't, offhand, know how to do that; but you want the output from netstat to look more like

```
tcp      0    0 0.0.0.0:3306              0.0.0.0:*                 LISTEN
```

Your third problem will be that adding a NAT rule for port-forwarding doesn't implicitly punch that forwarded traffic through the firewall.  Having redirected incoming traffic on TCP/33306, you'll still need to allow the resulting redirected traffic through the INPUT chain, with something like

```
iptables -I INPUT 8 -p tcp --dport 33306 -s a.b.c.d -j ACCEPT
```

where `a.b.c.d` is the IP address of the server you want to be able to so communicate.

**Re-edit:** OK, you've decided that `mysqld` can only bind to localhost, but you're willing to get rid of the 33306/3306 distinction, and have the incoming client connect to port 3306.

That given, I think you have a problem; we can't use SNAT to rewrite the packets as if they came from `localhost`, because the traffic isn't leaving the box, so the packets won't pass through the nat table's `POSTROUTING` chain, which is the only place SNAT is a valid target.  I don't think you can easily do this with iptables, and that either an SSH connection or a VPN which provides logical interfaces, such as OpenVPN, will be needed; sorry.

Comment: thank you. sure I messed up destination. But isn't there a way to let mysql like it is, I mean bound to 127.0.0.1 and forward the outer port there?

Comment: Pauel, forgive me for saying this if you already know it, but local etiquette is that *once you're happy with an answer* to your question, you accept it by ticking the tick outline next to it.  That drives SF's reputation system for the both of us.  I note you've been a member for some time, but you've not asked a qustion before, so hopefully my comments not too out-of-place.

Comment: I'm relatively new to serverfault but I get that. my issue is not really fixed. changing the mysql config to listen to 0.0.0.0 is not an option, so I still need to forward or route the traffic to 127.0.0.1:3306 somehow. I'm not a pro in iptables :-) Thx for your help

Comment: I understand you're not fixed yet; acceptance applies only when you're happy.  That said, this requirement to have mysqld listen only on localhost is complicating matters; see edit above.

Comment: Maybe I should reconsider. I have mysql on 127.0.0.1:3306 and can't change that. So what about your suggestion to open 3306. There would still be the problem that mysql is not listening?

Comment: should I ask a separate question?

Comment: Hey @MadHatter, like I said I'm not a crack in iptables, could you please give me a hand on this problem outside od serverfault?

Comment: I've put my best guess above.  I'm happy to assist you outside SF; my contact details can be found in my profile (click on the company link); but you should understand that this is what I do for a living, and if you approach me directly it'll be on a professional basis.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8416/discussion-between-pauel-and-madhatter)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it's not a good idea to mess up things like I tried before and changed etc/mysql/my.cnf to fit a normal setup like:

```
# bind to all ip's
bind to 0.0.0.0
```

I also restricted the connections for port 3306 to an IP:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 --src xxx.x.x.xx -j ACCEPT
```

Drop all traffic to that port that is not allowed:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

If someone has a better and more secure way to get it done please let me know.